# Mysql server. Why does it speed up after a restart?

Tags: mysql

I'm running a drupal 7 site locally using mamp.

Sometimes the site runs really slowly (and feels like it hits a bottle next, 5 pages will load really slowly then all of a sudden they instantly load). However, when I restart mysql it speeds right up.

Why is this?

Comment: You might have mysql misconfigured and it's trying to use more resources than there are available on the OS (eg. use more memory and it starts swapping)

Comment: Impossible to say, but it could be that your server is doing some heavy work. When you restart mysql it has obviously stopped doing that work (as it's now doing nothing). It could also be that your settings make your mysql use too much memory, and you are swapping. Restarting clears all caches etc, so you're in the clear a bit.

Comment: "restart MySQL" or "restart the computer"?

Comment: There can be many reasons, but the most likely is that MySQL gets moves from the memory to the disk (swap) which causes slowdowns. That's why you usually want to have database servers on a different machine.

Comment: How can I tell if it's misconfigured? Can you point me to some idiot proof / easy to understand guides?